# running standalone JPA with datasource in persistence.xml

Tags: eclipselink

```
Below is my perisistence.xml, having the datasource.

<persistence-unit name="employee" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDS</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am trying to createEntityManager in standalone and cannot execute a sample query,
 please help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Ensure RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions is used.
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType",
            PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL.name());

        // Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" , "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "scott");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "tiger");

        // Ensure that no server-platform is configured
        properties.put("eclipselink.target-server", TargetServer.None);

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME,properties);
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();                 
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(" select d from  XyzEntity d");
        List<XyzEntity> xyzEntityList = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("size is"+xyzEntityList.size());
    }
```

The above code is still looking for the datasource.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the <non-jta-data-source> tag, delete the properties you put in the class, and add them in the persistence.xml file, like this:

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="the.driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="the url"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="the user"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="the pass"/>
</properties>
```

You need to add your persistence provider too, below the <persistence-unit> tag:

```
<provider>bla.bla.bla.bla.BlaProvider</provider>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to inject EntityManager instance using @PersistenceContext annotation in an example having persistence.xml, similar to the one above. I specified transaction-type="JTA". But, I am still getting EntityManager instance as null. It's not getting injected. I have specified the properties as specified in this answer. What configuration do I need to still change? I am doing it in a standalone java application.

Comment: If you are in a standalone application, you can't use a JTA environment, you have to control your transactions with a custom transaction manager, you can open a new question with your problem.